# Совместное использование Razor и Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, mvc, сериализация

Как в представлении mvc-приложения можно выполнить проверку модели на **null** с помощью Javascript-функции? Проблема в том, что если использовать `@if(Model != null){}` то не могу реализовать дальнейшую работу со скриптом и использование полученного результата. Конечная цель функции - передать сериализованную модель в контроллер

#### Controller

```
public class MyController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(MyModel objectModel)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### Models

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Period Period { get; set; }
}
public class Period
{
    public int? ExtraTime { get; set; }
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
    $("#save").click(function() {            
    var objectModel = null;

    //не получается выполнить проверку
    if (Model != null) {
        objectModel = {
            "Name": '@Model.Name',
            "Description": '@Model.Description',
            "Period": { "ExtraTime": 12 }
        };
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Edit")',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(objectModel),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

Comment: razor по умолчанию обрабатывает только cshtml файлы если скрипт не в таком файле - то и соответственно этот файл не будет обработан. Так же стоит помнить, что razor выполняется на сервере, а яваскрипт на клиенте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@if (Model != null) {
    <text>
    objectModel = {
        "Name": '@Model.Name',
        "Description": '@Model.Description',
        "Period": { "ExtraTime": 12 }
    };
    </text>
}
```

вот, если так вставишь теги **text**, то выполнится задуманная проверка на **null**
[и тут более подробно](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax)

Comment: только если данный код будет обработан razor'ом